# How to get matching values between two dates that are in mongo's documents?

Tags: mongodb, datetime, aggregation-framework, match, momentjs

I'm trying to match the values greater than and less than a datetime parameter which holds the value for the current date time after it's been formatted with `momentjs`.

The datetime variable

`datetime = moment.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ')`

The values I'm trying to match exist in a mongo's document as seen here in the picture

[image]

The code I used for matching :

```
if (_params.datetime) {
          _mongoParams.push({
            $and: [
              {
                _rewards: {
                  _endDatetime: { $lte: new Date(datetime) }
                },
              },
              {
                _rewards: {
                  _startDatetime: { $gte: new Date(datetime) }
                },
              }
            ],
          })
        }
```

The problem is I'm not getting any results when I try to make requests with the `datetime` parameter. I tried placing the `datetime` variable inside an ISODate constructor but it didn't work too.
How can I possibly match the dates ?

Comment: Are your date fields strings? One of the common mistakes is comparing strings with dates, which will yield no result.

Comment: +1 to @ray's comment about type mismatch. Another question - what does your schema actually look like?  It's unclear if `_rewards` is the parent field of those two date fields based just on that screenshot.